# I just got a remote job but have to travel to corporate sometimes. Is it typical for the company to pay all travel expenses?

Tags: telecommute, travel, expenses

I have traveled for business all my life and companies have always paid for all travel expense. However, I have never worked remotely, so when I accepted the job, I did not think to ask if they cover all business expenses when I have to go to headquarters (this involves a flight). I will be asking after I start, but would like to know what is typically covered.

For example, do I pay for lunch, but they pay for dinner since office employees usually pay for their own lunch, or do they pay for all meals since I am traveling? If they say they only pay for some of the expenses (air/hotel) but expect me to pay for airport parking, airline baggage fees, ground transportation, this would be something I totally did not anticipate.

What is typical for remote employees required to go to headquarters?

Comment: I have a feeling this will depend on your organization's policy.

Comment: This is almost definitely company specific

Comment: Whilst "Will my company pay for my travel expenses?" is company-specific, OP is actually asking "What is typical in the industry?", which I feel is on-topic (answers can always point out that there will be a certain amount of variance per company).

Comment: Why are you asking us instead of asking your own HR?

Comment: In what country is that? In mine (France), the company has to pay for all the expenses, by law, except for some specific cases and then only when written in the employment contract.

Comment: @startplusplus There is no 'typical for the industry' if the OP does not even mention in what branch of industry (s)he works. It can also be culture-dependent and (s)he does not mention geographical area. Voting to close.

Comment: What do you mean you just got it? You accepted a job without talking about compensation?

Answer (score 8):

Generally, yes, travel expenses are covered by companies when employees travel for business. This commonly includes lodging, meals, flights, transportation, etc. Keep in mind there are generally restrictions on cost amounts (for example only $15/lunch reimbursement).

You will want to save all receipts in the event you need to provide them to be reimbursed.

I currently am working remote (from my team, at least) and will have my travel expenses completely covered when I travel to our headquarters.

However, because each company will have slightly different policies - the actionable answer will be to talk with your manager to determine what your company specific policy is.

Comment: An alternative might be that you get travel and lodging reimbursed, and a per diem for the food. You'll get the fixed amount of money, no need to hold on to receipts.

Answer (score 3):

This depends.  We have employees just like you on our staff - huge global.

It depends on two things.  Your contract and your location.

During hiring process if you lived in Buffalo, NY and work remotely throughout the Northeast and Canada but report into New York, NY, then there would be two options (trying to give you real world example I know of).

1. You stipulate that company incurs cost for travel to NYC.  The stipulation might just include travel and lodging.  Since it is your primary location they would not pay for added expenses (at my company).  But you can ask for anything.
2. Since NYC is your primary location the company expects that you are in the office X number of days a month.  Since you are accepting a job in NYC under this agreement and it is your primary location then you would get no travel money or expenses paid for.

On a side note, (at my company) if you were in Buffalo with primary location NYC, then anywhere else other than NYC the company would pay for travel.

Comment: +1 for mention of the contract.  I went from full time onsite to full time remote and part of the deal we worked out was that I would travel 6 times a year back to "headquarters" with travel expenses paid by me and lodging while there paid by them.   I should add that it was explicitly spelled out that way in the agreement.